# Automatización de busqueda inconclusa por lentitud de carga en el DOM

Tags: python, selenium

estoy tratando de automatizar un proceso de busqueda de elementos en una pagina web usando selenium, el problema esta en que debido a que la conexión de internet es lenta obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Angel\Desktop\nuevo\main.py", line 53, in <module>
    getPrecioPublico = precioPublico.get_attribute('innerHTML')
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 172, in get_attribute
    attribute_value = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 493, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
```

He tratado de manejar el error usando la exclusión de excepciónes de Selenium pero aun asi no funciona y sigue arrojando el error.

Este es mi código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.steren.com.mx/")

exeptionIgnored = (NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)

lista = [
    "CCTV-235",
    "AUD-7660",
    "THEB-3/16",
    "SHOME-120",
    "SHOME-122",
    "509-015",
    "LAM-055",
    "PCAJA-001",
    "CRG-020",
    "BAT-HA-312",
    "BAT-CR2450",
    "BAT-CR1620"
]


for elemento in lista:

    inputSearch = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"q") # Barra de busqueda en HTML
    inputSearch.send_keys(elemento)
    inputSearch.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    try:
        productImage = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"product-image-photo").click()

        contenedorPrecioMayoreo = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#venta-mayoreo p")
        precioDistribuidor = contenedorPrecioMayoreo[1].get_attribute('innerHTML')
        
        precioPublico = WebDriverWait(driver,50,ignored_exceptions=exeptionIgnored)\
                                        .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".price")))
        
        print("\n\n{}\n\n".format(precioPublico))

        getPrecioPublico = precioPublico.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        
        
    

        regla = re.compile("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+")
        precioFinal = re.findall(regla,precioDistribuidor)

        precioPublicoFinal = re.findall(regla,getPrecioPublico)

        nombreProducto = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.base")
        getNombreProducto = nombreProducto.get_attribute('innerHTML')


        print(getNombreProducto,precioFinal[0],precioPublicoFinal[0])

    
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Not Found")

    newInputSearch = WebDriverWait(driver, 20,ignored_exceptions=exeptionIgnored)\
                                    .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"q")))
    
    newInputSearch.clear()
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a resolverlo

Comment: Si te fijas la página que usas tiene protección.

Comment: @Mateo, en ese caso que puedo hacer?

Comment: Aparentemente cloudflare detecta que se está intentando usar un navegador automatizado. Probablemente te interese investigar un poco sobre medidas para evitarlo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec https://piprogramming.org/articles/How-to-make-Selenium-undetectable-and-stealth--7-Ways-to-hide-your-Bot-Automation-from-Detection-0000000017.html

Comment: Como comentan mas arriba, la pagina https://www.steren.com.mx/ tiene proteccion anti automatizacion. Si estas probando paginas recomiendo esta https://cl.abstracta.us/blog/mejores-sitios-web-prueba-practicar-tests/  si en el caso de que esa pagina es parte de tu aplicacion, pide a desarrollo que quite esa restriccion en QA, para que tu puedes automatizar el sitio